# How to add a Button/Link to the last item in a list of search results

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to add a button to the last item in the list of results I am generating using `JQuery` `Autocomplete`. Currently, each list item is created like so:

```
create: function(item) { 
    $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $('<li>')
       .append('<a>' + item.label + " " + " - " + item.type +'</a>')
       .appendTo(ul);
    };
```

},

What I'd like to do is when I get to the last element in the list add a button, however I can't figure out how to do that. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery pseudo selector to get the last item.

`$('li:last')`

Comment: Ok cool, I'll give that a shot. So if I append to the last item I'm adding a new `li` essentially right?